# define a Linear Time-Delay system in Mathematica and plot it's Bode and Nyquist diagrams

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, mathematica-8, control-theory

I have a characteristic equation of a time-delay system and i can't define it with `StateSpaceModel` or `TransferFunctionModel` command in *Mathematica*; Because these commands only work for linear systems without delay.

My purpose is to define a Time-Delay system in *Mathematica 8.0.1* and plotting [*Bode* Diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bode_plot) and [*Nyquist* Diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist_plot) for a system like this:

```
g = ((s + 1) (1-E^(-2 s) + E^(-3 s)))/(s^2 + 2 s + 10)
```

Answer (score 0):

Judging from the documentation, it seems MMA expects transfer functions to be polynomial. The doc page for TransferFunctionModel says:

> In
>   TransferFunctionModel[{num,den},var]
>   num must be a polynomial matrix and
>   den can be specified as a polynomial
>   matrix or just the common denominator
>   polynomial.

All the examples I have seen have polynomials in the nominator and denominator.

Matlab's bodeplot also doesn't do pure time delays.

One sometimes hears the suggestion to use a Padé approximation of the exponential. This could be done with the mma function `PadeApproximant`.

[image]

However, this seems to be valid only for rather low frequencies (the first 180 degrees of phase change or so) as stated [here](http://www.mathkb.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/matlab/8262/Bode-plot-of-time-delay).

Comment: I know that, what is your suggestion to plot _Bode_ and _Nyquist_ diagram of my problem.

Comment: I don't want to  use _Pade_ approximation method.I think i should write a code and substitution `g/.{s-> j w}` and calculate _Magnitude_ and _Phase_ of Complex value of g and then plot _Magnitude_ and _Phase_ respect to `w` for _Bode Plot_ and for _Nyquist Diagram_ calculate Real and Imaginary Part of `g/.{s->j w}` and then plot Imaginary part respect to real part for a range of frequency (w).